# How to print 1 to 10 by every second?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print 1 to 10 in 10 seconds. It's looping numbers but 1 number per second

The result should be like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: `time.sleep(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sleep() to make it wait for the required time

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    print(i+1)
    sleep(1)
```